# Multiple .htaccess rules for same directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm new to using .htaccess files and I've ran into a problem. When I declare multiple rules for the same directory (news), it only seems to trigger the first rule.

In this case the only RewriteRule that works is
RewriteRule ^news news.php [NC,L]

However the second rule for ^news which includes the parameters id and title doesn't trigger.

What is the correct way to declare multiple rules for the news directory?

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^news news.php [NC, L]



#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: `,L` means "last", remove that in your first rule https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Even when I remove the L the second rule still doesn't trigger

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news$ news.php [NC,QSA,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,QSA,END]
```

The *main* issue with your attempt was that you forgot to terminate the matching pattern in your first rule... `^news` will match any string that *starts* with "news". You said nothing about anything following afterwards. For that you will need to anchor the pattern to the subject end: `^news$`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would expect the server to respond to "the first matching rule that it encountered, and then stop looking."

As you see, it can be very tricky to "get the rules right."